# how to get a foreignkey object to display full object in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django back-end built with `django_rest_framework`. I currently have an object that is a foreign key. When I make a API request to grab an object it displays the foreignkey id and only the id. I want it to display the entire object rather than just the id of the foriegnkey. Not sure how to do it because it did not really show how to do it in the documentation.

Here is the code:

**Views page:**

```
from users.models import Profile
from ..serializers import ProfileSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

There is a user foreign key referring to the user.

**Urls:**

```
from users.api.views.profileViews import ProfileViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', ProfileViewSet, base_name='profile')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**The serializer:**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'synapse',
            'bio',
            'profile_pic',
            'facebook',
            'twitter'
        )
```

**This is what it looks like:**

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user": 3,
        "bio": "software engineer",
        "profile_pic": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/profile/profile_pics/allsum-logo-1.png",
        "facebook": "http://www.facebook.com/",
        "twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/"
    }
]
```

Comment: You can create a `UserSerializer` and use it as a field on `ProfileSerializer`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [**`depth=1`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in your **`Meta`** class of serializer,

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'synapse',
            'bio',
            'profile_pic',
            'facebook',
            'twitter'
        )
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Spend a long time trying to make this work with SlugRelatedField...

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `UserSerializer` and use it in `ProfileSerializer` like this(using as [nested serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            # and so on..
         )

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'synapse',
            'bio',
            'profile_pic',
            'facebook',
            'twitter'
        )
```